# Dreamweaver 8 Not Starting on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, wine

I've been trying to start Dreamweaver 8 in Wine with winetricks installed in Ubuntu 10.04LTS and it would simply show that it was loading and then stop, so I decided to try in the terminal to see what I would get and I recieve.

```
 wine Dreamweaver.exe
err:module:attach_process_dlls "odbc32.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files\\Macromedia\\Dreamweaver 8\\Dreamweaver.exe" failed, status c0000005
doxramos@doxramos-laptop:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Macromedia/Dreamweaver 8$
```

odbc32.dll is installed within the libraries and is in my System32 Folder inside of Wine. Does anyone know what could cause this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3482&iTestingId=70704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Mdac27 and 28 within Wine Tricks seems to have fixed the issue. If anyone else has this issue type ./winetricks in a terminal windows. 
Select the default wineprefix
Install a Windows Component or DLL
Then select Mdac27 and Mdac28 and follow any on screen commands you have.